# How to install HP Scanjet 8270 in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 14.04, 12.04, hp, scanner, hplip

I have HP Scanjet 8270 Scanner and want to install in my ubuntu 12.04. How to install it? I tried HPLIP, HP Toolkit and search through internet. but nothing works. So, how to install it?

Comment: I've searched the HP support site, and they don't mention Linux. Have you tried `sane - scanner graphical frontends`?

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot get free drivers working (and I'm having trouble finding any for your scanner), you could use **VueScan**, which is  commercial (proprietary) scanning software that works on Linux. It appears to support the HP ScanJet 8200 Series.

There is a free trial of VueScan downloadable at https://www.hamrick.com/ that you can try out to see if it works with your scanner; however, to remove the watermarks on scanned images you will need to buy a license, which is normally $49.95 for the Standard Edition (but is currently on sale for $39.95).

(I have no affiliation with the makers of VueScan, but I have used it to get my HP scanner working)

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 16.04, I installed XSane (version 0.999) and the package "simple-scan". In XSane I configured the preferences as follows:

[image]

Number of pages to scan: greater or equal to the number of pages in the automatic docu feed tray of the scanner
Select target: Save
Select scan source: ADF Front
Set up the image quality and file naming

Then start the scan.

→ Works perfectly.